# @Validation inside the method signature

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I would like to @Validate if the password is longer than 3 characters but smaller than 100 chars. How can I do that inside the method signature by using annotations ? I tried something like this.

```
public void changePassword(@Size(min = 4, max = 100) @RequestBody String password) {
        userService.changePassword(password);
   }
```

but it is not working. Anyone knows how to change it  ?

P.S. I do not want to implement a simple method that checks the length, I want to do it with annotations. Thank you

Comment: and what is stopping you? do you intend to create your own annotations? not entirely sure how this would be done, though

Comment: No, I want to use @Size annotation, but I can not make it work here.

Comment: have you checked the code for that annotation? to see on which targets it can be applied?

Comment: I think you have to use the @Valid in addition to RequestBody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the annotation in the model class. You can not write it in the method signature, according to the Java rules. So, put @Size(min = 4, max = 100), before the field in the model class. Hope this helps you.